# ggplot data with missing months and blue shade for spring period in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following `data.frame` where I am missing winter months (Nov, Dec, Jan, and Feb). When I `ggplot` the data, I see that the lines are connected even though there is no data for the winter months. I would like to avoid having those missing months drawn on the graph. Also, I would like to draw a blue shade for the spring months (March, April, May) that would indicate spring period.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                  Obs = runif(1826,1,5), Sim = runif(1826,1,5)) %>% 
   separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
  filter(between(Month, 3,10)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, Day))

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Sim, col = "red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Obs, col = "blue"))
```

**Desired output:** I am looking for a plot like below where the spring period is highlighted with blue shade.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#Data
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 Obs = runif(1826,1,5), Sim = runif(1826,1,5)) %>% 
  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
  filter(between(Month, 3,10)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, Day))
#Create springs var
DF <- DF %>% mutate(Spring=ifelse(Month %in% c('03','04','05'),'Spring',NA)) %>%
  filter(!Month %in% c('11','12'))
#Plot
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Date,group=Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Sim, col = "red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Obs, col = "blue"))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(x=Date,y=5,fill=Spring),alpha=0.25)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue'),
                     labels=c('Sim','Obs'))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.5,0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('blue','pink'),
                    limits='Spring')+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA,5),expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(paste0(unique(format(DF$Date,'%Y-%m')),'-01')),
               date_labels = '%Y-%m',expand = c(0.05,0))+
  theme_bw()+labs(color='',fill='')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(-0.5, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_blank())+
  facet_wrap(.~Year,scales = 'free_x',nrow = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duck, is there a way to completely avoid having those white space for the missing months? ie. Drawing month 3 - 10 data but with no gaps for the missing months.

Comment: Also i see that the shaded bar has y-scale (y = 5). Can it be defined in such a way where we dont need to specify the y value? you can see that it leave white spaces at the top. depends what the data range is, it would do same thing

Comment: @Hydro Added an update, it is the most you can reduce that space because of your date variable.